# Install Qt for Visual Studios express 2013 IntelliSense issue

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I am following a online tutorial on using openGL and Qt. Here is the link: 
[Youtube Vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLvxLkgHqQs&list=PLRwVmtr-pp06qT6ckboaOhnm9FxmzHpbY&index=2)

After trying what he says and following the advice of other questions online, I still cannot get QT to work with Visual Studios Express 2013. I am not sure if the reason it is not working is because I am using and express edition or because I did not install the Qt plugin for VS which says it does not [work for any express edition.](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Anyways, the error I am getting is:

`IntelliSense: cannot open source file "../../src/gui/kernel/qapplication.h"`

And all I have written so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Qt\qapplication.h>


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    //QApplication
}
```

The version of qt I downloaded was Qt libraries 4.8.6 for Windows (VS 2010, 236 MB).

Comment: You will run into more issues than that when you use a version of Qt that was not built with the same compiler as you use. This will cause you to have 2 independent heaps 1 for the .dlls that are compiled with Qt and have Visual Studio 2010 runtimes and a second heap for your Visual Studio 2013 application. Having 2 heaps will lead to heap corruption and random application crashes.

Comment: thanks for the help... so you're saying I should install either the newest qt version or a previous visual studios version?

Comment: just installed vs2010 express edition... no luck

Comment: I use 4.8.6 with VS2010 Pro daily for years however I am using CMake to add Qt support to my projects so my setup is different. This evening (12 or so hours from now) I will take a look at the tutorial to see if I see anything. Also IntelliSense errors are not necessarily real errors. IntelliSense uses a partial compile while you type so that it can understand some of your symbols. These errors do not always translate to compiler errors when you build your application.

Comment: Also for your include I would normally `#include <QApplication>` not `#include <Qt\qapplication.h>`